# using jqxgrid exportdata to xls causes leaving encrypted connection. How to prevent it?

Tags: encryption, export-to-excel, jqxgrid, insecure-connection

Im am using jqxgrid export data functionality:

```
$("#jqxGrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'xls', fileName);
```

But this causes the data to leave encrypted connection and be sent over unencrypted connection. And third party can easily read the data. Since it may be sensitive information, is it possible for me to prevent it from leaving secure connection while still using the feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqWidgets needs to send your grid data to a server, so this server can resend it to the user. This is how the user get the file like a download, you can't do that only on client side.

When you call 'exportdata', it uses a file which is located on jqWidgets' servers. You have to add the URL of your own server to make sure it won't send data to a third party. Look a the API here : http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-api.htm

Comment: But then dos that not require me to have the actual exporting mechanism in my server? How do I get the file for that?

Comment: Yes, you need a file on your server to take the data from javascript and repush it to the user.